# The URI urn:this-stylesheet does not identify an external Java class

Tags: xml, xslt

I am debugging a XSLT and seeing the below error

```
 <xsl:function name="this:sendquotedvalue" as="xs:string">
calling using the below lines
<xsl:value-of select="this:sendquotedvalue($emptyString)"/>
```

error i am getting is

```
The URI urn:this-stylesheet does not identify an external Java class
```

also have urn as below

```
xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet"
```

Any suggestion

-Prasanna.K

Comment: Use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9 or 10 if you want to use `xsl:function`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your stylesheet specifies version="2.0" (or higher), but you are running it under an XSLT 1.0 processor.

A 1.0 processor is required to ignore declarations like `xsl:function` if the stylesheet version is greater than 1.0 (this is called "forwards compatibility mode"). So the `xsl:function` doesn't exist, which makes the attempt to call this function an error. For a 1.0 Java processor, there are only two kinds of functions that it knows about: built in core functions (in no namespace), and external Java functions. It's ruled out the first category because there's a namespace, and now it's telling you that it can't be an external Java function either, because the namespace doesn't map to any external Java class.

Note that specifying version="2.0" in a stylesheet doesn't magically give you an XSLT 2.0 processor; the rules for loading an XSLT processor (such as the JAXP factory rules) don't take the stylesheet version into account.

Comment: Thanks Michael so much. might be the reason. I am using oxygen XML editor and kindly can you please throw some settings where i need to change this or install XSLT processor 2.0.

Comment: @PrasannaK, it might depend on the exact oXygen version you use but when setting up a transformation scenario https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/23.1/ug-editor/topics/xslt-tab.html then make sure you select Saxon 9 or Saxon 10 as the XSLT processor, not Xalan or Saxon 6